# I have a data set with two columns. How do I rotate it from long format to wide format?

Tags: sql

**Request for immediate assistance**

My table has the following columns:

```
subject1| subject2 
   2    |    4    
   2    |    5    
   2    |    6    
   2    |    8  
   4    |    7    
   4    |    11    
   6    |    9    
   6    |    10  
   6    |    12  
   10   |    15    
   10   |    16    
   13   |    14    
   16   |    17
```

Now i need data in this format:

```
2  | 4  | 5 | 6 | 8 | 7 | 11 | 9 | 10 | 12 | 15 | 16 | 17
13 | 14
```

As you can see i want to transpose 2nd column by 1st column.

Thanks

Comment: Search here for `[sql] pivot table`, and choose the one that is applicable to the particular SQL database you're using.

Comment: What do you mean by not simple format? Can you explain more?

Comment: Dear  Kuzgun, so thanks for you. It is mean that if i want do a simple transpose, then my expect output has the following format:   2 | 4| 5| 6| 8;               
4 | 7| 11;  
6 | 9| 10 | 12;                   
10| 15| 16;            13 | 14;            16 | 17;                But it is not my purpose.

Comment: Hello everybody. Really i need this program. Please help me for do that.